# When starting a discord bot i get this error

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

When starting my discord bot that I created a couple years ago I'm getting this error, I've no clue on whats causing it. I have done the uninstall of the node_modules and reinstalling etc but I'm not sure what the error could be caused by, any ideas?

Error:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Bot> node index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'better-sqlite3'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Bot\node_modules\enmap\src\index.js
- C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Bot\node_modules\enmap\index.js
- C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Bot\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at new Enmap (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Bot\node_modules\enmap\src\index.js:110:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Bot\index.js:5:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Bot\\node_modules\\enmap\\src\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Bot\\node_modules\\enmap\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Bot\\index.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you install and defined `better-sqlite3` ?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure better-sqlite3 is installed

```
npm i better-sqlite3
```

then that it has been defined

```
const better-sqlite3 = require('better-sqlite3')
```